# Calcular pixels para colunas no css

Tags: html, css

Bom galera tenho 3 colunas em um espaço de 950px;

Fiz os cálculos aqui na calculadora **950/3 = 316,6666666666667**

Só que quando converto isso pra css:

`width: 316.6666666666667px;` nada muda, ele pega como se fosse `width: 316px;`, preciso que ele preencha a tela toda, fica faltando um fiozinho de cabelo, mas não preenche.

E preciso de um espaçamento de `10px` para cada coluna, menos a primeira coluna.

Meu código html e css:

```
<div class="works">
  <h2>Serviços</h2>

  <div class="works-boxes">
    a
  </div>

  <div class="works-boxes">
    a
  </div>

  <div class="works-boxes">
    a
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.works-boxes {
    width: 316.66667px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o espaço é de 10px, nao tem pra que complicar, dá pra dividir certinho os 950px.

- 310px por coluna
- 10px de margem

Veja em modo "página toda":

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.works {
  background:#ff0;
  width:950px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.works-boxes {
  width:310px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  background:#fc0;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.works-boxes:first-of-type {
  margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
  <h2>Serviços</h2>

  <div class="works-boxes">
    a
  </div>

  <div class="works-boxes">
    a
  </div>

  <div class="works-boxes">
    a
  </div>
</div>
```

### Pontos de interesse:

- `box-sizing: border-box;` - isto serve para que o padding e as bordas não atrapalhem a contabilização das medidas. As bordas serão incluidas na medida original, e não acrescentadas.
- `.works-boxes:first-of-type` - isto serve para não ter os 10px antes da primeira caixa. Se não quer usar este tipo de seletor, basta usar algo do tipo `class="works-boxes first"`, e usar o `.first` como seletor.
- `overflow:auto;` - sem isto, o float faz com que as `div`s internas escapem do `.works`, atrapalhando o uso do espaço.

O resto é decoração, para você visualizar melhor na tela o que está acontecendo.

Depender de "arredondamento de pixel" geralmente é pedir pra ter dor de cabeça.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo, `first-of-type` é nova pra mim, eu conhecia o `first-child` `nth-child` e `last-child`.

Comment: Se quiser maior compatibilidade com navegadores mais velhos, pode fazer o que eu comentei, use uma classe normal, e no primeiro ponha `class="works-boxes first"`

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO veja uma versão simplificada http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/aNVRoY

Comment: Deu certinho fera, e vou fazer com essa dica sua ai fica até mais organizado até.